# Ubuntu 20.04 - Black screen and no response to input after reboot

Tags: boot, gnome, 20.04, reboot, teamviewer

I have a Desktop PC running Ubuntu 20.04. I mainly connect to this computer using TeamViewer (it's in the office and I'm working from home like so many of us). The computer's been working fine for about a year now. However, this morning when I connected to it the screen was frozen. I did a reboot and after that all I get is a black screen. I can still connect with TeamViewer but I just get a black screen and it doesn't respond to any mouse or keyboard input. I can connect and interact with it through SSH so obviously it's still online, it seems it's just the GUI (gnome) that's not working.

Grateful for any advice here.

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by a simple cold-reset. As for the root cause I just don't know for sure.